# OpenCart module on product page based on route

Tags: php, opencart

I have set up 2 modules on the left column, one with categories & one with manufacturers,
both with their own layouts: product/category & product/manufacturer,

this works fine as it should: when browsing categories, only the category module is shown in the left column, and when browsing manufacturers only the canufacturers module is shown in the left column.

But when checking product details, it will only show modules assigned to the layout "product",
and here is where I can't get my head around what to do. 
If adding layout "product" to both category & manufacturer module, then (of course) both modules are shown, how can add module based on route?

Example Browsing Categorys:

1) Only categories module is shown in the left column (all good here)

```
index.php?route=product/category&path=33
```

2) entering product :

```
index.php?route=product/product&path=33&product_id=31
```

now all modules assigned to layout "product" is shown, and I just want the module
shown when browsing Category (step1) to be shown

Example Browsing Manufacturers:

1) Only Manufacturer module is shown in the left column (all good here)

```
index.php?route=product/manufacturer
```

2) entering the same product as in the category example:

```
index.php?route=product/product&manufacturer_id=9&product_id=31
```

now all modules assigned to layout "product" is shown, and I just want the module
shown when browsing Manufacturers (step1) to be shown

So it's two different routes to the same product:

```
index.php?route=product/product&path=33&product_id=31
index.php?route=product/product&manufacturer_id=9&product_id=31
```

But the layout that applys are the one called "product" with route product/product

So is there a way to add those two different routes to two different layouts, so the modules could be shown correctly or Im I thinking the wrong way?

Any input on this would be great

OpenCart 1.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here. Either You could take a look at the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` header, which may not be sent (so is not 100% reliable), or You could use session to store the key of where are you coming from... E.g., when listing categories, in `category` controller do something like:

```
$this->session->data['user_is_listing'] = 'category';
```

If The user jumps to the manufacturers listing in `manufacturer` controller set the same key, different value:

```
$this->session->data['user_is_listing'] = 'manufacturer';
```

Then, in `column_left` controller add a new check for these two modules (*both manufacturer and category modules have to be assigned to the product detail page*) and check what value is stored in session under the key `user_is_listing`... Then, either allow the module rendering or not...

**EDIT:** OK, let's assume that Your own modules have names `category1` and `manufacturer1` (if You are using the default modules, then the names would be without number `1`). Now, in column left find the `foreach ($extensions as $extension) {` loop and we will modify it this way:

```
    foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
        $modules = $this->config->get($extension['code'] . '_module');

        if ($modules) {
            foreach ($modules as $module) {
                if ($module['layout_id'] == $layout_id && $module['position'] == 'column_left' && $module['status']) {
                    if ($route == 'product/product' && in_array($extension['code'], array('category1', 'manufacturer1'))) {
                        if($this->session->data['user_is_listing'] == $extension['code'])) {
                            $module_data[] = array(
                                'code'       => $extension['code'],
                                'setting'    => $module,
                                'sort_order' => $module['sort_order']
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $module_data[] = array(
                            'code'       => $extension['code'],
                            'setting'    => $module,
                            'sort_order' => $module['sort_order']
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it's necessary that the name stored in the session is the same as the name of that module.

Comment: thanks, but not sure what you mean with "add a new check for these two modules"? I have them assigned to the product detail page (layout: product, route: product/product), so should the value check go into      if ($route == 'product/product' in column_left.php?

Comment: OK I'm stuck at controller column_left.php. When echo $this->session->data['user_is_listing']; I've got correct "manufacturer" och "category" printed out, but not sure how to render it.

Comment: UPDATE: I used CSS to hide the boxes while I'm figuring out how to render, but got a new problem, if leaving to category from manufacturers and using the browsers back button back to manufacturers, all looks fine at first, but when clicking on a manufacturer in the list, the category session kicks in. Is this expected behavior with this sollution?

Comment: Check my edited answer. It is more just a hint, I didn't test the code, but it may work out of the box...

Comment: Works perfect out of the box! Only setback with this is direct links. If you bookmark a www.myshop.com/manufacturer/product01, it will show correct breadcrumbs but with the categories module, unless your last browsing was manufacturers, in which case www.myshop.com/category/product01 direct link will have the manufacturer menu displayed.

Comment: Then You can change that one condition to check only for the actual URL (not the rewritten one to `index.php?route=...`) anc check, whether the `manufacturer` or `category` are part of it... Then You can forget about this SESSION key...

Comment: Will have a try to see if I can make it work, so it must be the actual URL, meaning if adding a new category I need to add that manually each time aswell?

Comment: FOLLOWUP QUESTION: How can this be added on modules? I splitted up the menu into two modules so I have a part showing on layout "category" and another on layout "information", but the menu added on information is shown when entering a product thru category. Tryed to add the above code to the controller module/information but its not working.

Comment: All the changes should be done in the above controller... Modules should be simple and they shouldn't decide whether and where to display, it is up to the module positions (left, right columns, top and bottom content) which module is rendered. Try to adjust the logic above to meet Your requirement...

Comment: OK then I have a problem, I though it was a basic thing, but cant figure it out how to do it in OpenCart, I just want PAGE1 with CATMENU1 listing products, when entering a product CATMENU1 shows. Same logic with PAGE2 & CATEMENU2 and PAGE3 & CATEMENU3. I've made pages/layouts with its own routes, just like the information pages. so I got page1/page1 as route, I can add the splitted CATMENU1 there (and using override for the categorys to layout PAGE1), so they list nicely, BUT when entering a product it shows CATMENU1, CATMENU2, CATMENU3 on the product. Is this the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I am afraid it would be better to create a new question for this... And explain properly what do You want to achieve... I am being lost in this now...