# OpenCart Split category on more pages

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to achieve the following:

Top Menu with CATEGORY GROUP1, CATEGORY GROUP2, CATEGORY GROUP3

When choosing CATEGORY GROUP1 all categorys in that group will be listed in left column.

So left bar would look like this:

CATEGORY GROUP1 category11

CATEGORY GROUP1 category12

CATEGORY GROUP1 category13

etc

and when choosing a product, only this CATEGORY GROUP1 should be visible in left column,

And when choosing CATEGORY GROUP2 in Top Menu I want the left column to only show:

CATEGORY GROUP2 Category21

CATEGORY GROUP2 Category22

CATEGORY GROUP2 Category23

etc

and when choosing a product from this list, I only want the CATEGORY GROUP2 to be visible in the left column

Same thing with CATEGORY GROUP 3.

Just cant figure out how to do this since if you add the category module to layout "Product" it will be visible every time you are in the product.

I've tryed Split Categorys and adding different layouts to each split,
example route page1/page1, page2/page2, this works fine for just displaying the categorys on different pages, but as soon as you choose the product it shows all modules asigned to the product page.

How can this be done?

OpenCart 1.5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with a workaround.

I combined this answer:
[Adding CSS stylesheet to pages based on route in OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285961/adding-css-stylesheet-to-pages-based-on-route-in-opencart)

with this:
[OpenCart module on product page based on route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840898/opencart-module-on-product-page-based-on-route/)

Then I added a new layout so I could split up the categorys on different pages, 
and added display:none for the modules based on path to the product.

Works but not the best sollution.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want to achieve. I knew creating a new question is better. This could be done in `catalog/controller/module/category.php` controller, where the categories are retrieved for the root and the children are loaded. Change the code to this:

```
class ControllerModuleCategory extends Controller {
    protected function index($setting) {
        $this->language->load('module/category');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        } else {
            $parts = array();
        }

        if (isset($parts[0])) {
            $this->data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
        } else {
            $this->data['category_id'] = 0;
        }

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($this->data['category_id']);

        if (isset($parts[1])) {
            $this->data['child_id'] = $parts[1];
        } else {
            $this->data['child_id'] = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->data['categories'] = array();

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $category['category_id']));

            $children_data = array();

            if (!$this->data['category_id']) {
                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                    $total += $product_total;

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );      
                }
            }

            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $total . ')' : ''),
                'children'    => $children_data,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );  
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/category.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/category.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/category.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
```

This should work as expected as well as previously if no category id is provided...

Comment: Thanks but this just takes away the categorys on the left column and leaves the onces in the topmenu? Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. If I choose Category Group1, then category 11,12,13 is shown in the left column and when choosing a product, the categorys 11,12,13 are still there (image1+2), then when choosing Category Group2, the categorys 21,22,23 are shown in the left column instead and when choosing a product only those categorys are there. (image3+4) So kind of make the productpage inherit what you where on just before, hope it makes sence?

Comment: OK I solved it with CSS by adding different classes to body based on route, and simply show/hide the things I don't want. Not the ultimate sollution, but works. should I post the answer here or is too much of a dirty workaround?

Comment: IMHO it is a workaround but if it works, OFC post it here and accept it so that somebody may use it as well in the future ;-)